# Question on how to solve sin(θ)=−cos(θ)

Tags: trigonometry

in the interval of 0<θ<360
solve for θ
, the equation (1)
, I would just say tanθ=−1 ***(scernario 1)***
and solve that.

sinθ=−cosθ(1)

but what if i said sinθ+cosθ=0
then cosθ(tanθ+1)=0 ***(scenario 2)***
. I'd have solutions for cosθ=0
as well as tanθ=−1
, why is doing this method wrong since arithmetically going through the workings out it seems fine , but the solutions for cosθ=0
are wrong?

I'm trying to get a verdict on if the 2nd method is still right or wrong ? i have a feeling its wrong since the solutions dont work, but the process of me getting to cos(θ)⋅[tanθ+1]=0
seemed sound that I wouldnt realise it was wrong ?

How do I stop myself from carrying out this sort of working out ,is there a way for me to intuitively prove its wrong even before the equation ends up in the form of cos(θ)⋅[tanθ+1]=0
because if i carried out a similar working out for this question " Solve for theta ,sinθ=3sinθcosθ
" and solving it similarly like so I'd end up with sinθ(1−3cosθ)=0 ***(Scenario 3)***
,and it would give the right solutions.

So as you can see in all the cases whenever i divided by a trig function you're automatically assuming its not =0 , in some cases this will lose solutions as in the case of sinθ=3sinθcosθ where dividing through by sinθ would make you lose solutions to get 1=3cosθ , but in other case such as in ***scernario 1*** where i divide by cosθ to get tanθ and ***scenario 2*** where i divided by cosθ to get tanθ and +1, this wont make me lose solutions? in all the cases whenever i divided by a trig function you're automatically assuming its not =0

so how am i fundamentally supposed to know mid way through doing my working out if dividing through by a trig will make me lose solutions or not.......

the last two paragraphs were edits to the question .

Comment: You are going from solving $f(\theta)=0$ to solving $f(\theta)g(\theta)=0$.  This introduces solutions of the second equation which are not necessarily solutions of the first equation.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).